# How to make a BufferedImage out of other BufferedImage's?

Tags: java

```
public BufferedImage getMap()
{
    map1 = new BufferedImage(5000,5000,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = map1.getGraphics();
    for(int i = 0; i < imagesToRender.size(); i++)
    {
        g.drawImage(imagesToRender.get(i), xCoords.get(i), yCoords.get(i), sizes.get(i), sizes.get(i),null);
    }
    g.dispose();
    return map1;
}
```

I'm trying to make my first game on Java but seem to be running into a problem: it drops from 60FPS down to 13-21.. and the problem is occurring in this section of the code. I'm trying to take a bunch of `BufferedImage` from the `ArrayList<BufferedImage>` `imagesToRender`, with their respective x,y coordinates for where on `map1` they will be drawn. The idea is that I want to update the game map constantly with new images that have to be rendered into it. The FPS does not drop gradually: it starts and stays between 13 and 21 fps the whole time. Is it possible that this way just takes too much processing power? If so, are there any better methods? If not, how can I fix the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need 5000X5000 image? Do you really have so big screen resolution? Why can't you render really visible fragment using clip bounds?

Comment: 5000x5000 is far too big; you almost definitely don't have a screen resolution that large. You're rendering more than 12 1920x1080 regions each frame. Why not just draw it to the screen directly or draw only the region you need?

Comment: @StanislavL the plan was to constantly update the entire game map using this code, then take only a section of the map I want to show, then draw it on the screen. another piece of code takes a section of the map. I reduced it to 1000 by 1000, and it works fine now. thank you